# Parsing text in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

You have a blog.

You want certain combinations of symbols (i.e. :), :(, :p ...) to be parsed into emoticons before the post in the blog are printed on the screen.

Should this parsing be a responsibility of the Model, the View or the Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a View **Helper**. The helper should have a function that parses for the emoticons.

Think of this parsing as formatting for output, therefore, it should be handled in the View.

Comment: What if you need to do several kinds of parsing: emoticons, urls, emails, bbcode etc. all on one text. Wouldn't that look bad if done in the View?

Comment: It's common practice to use several helpers in the view. That is, after all, what they're for. Using these helper helps you to keep the view code clean. For example I often use FormHelper, HtmlHelper, JavascriptHelper, TimeHelper etc. in one view.

Comment: Sure, but I guess you use these helpers on different objects. Wouldn't you be concerned if you have to use multiple helpers on one object (in this case the blog post text)?

Comment: @Emanuil: It's bad if the controller is formatting html output. It should only pass raw data, not decide how it should be displayed. That's the view's job.

Comment: @webbiedave, when you put it like that it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: No, AntonioCS. View helpers are functions/classes made specifically for use in views.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to store them parsed or raw?

If the former, the controller or model, depending on how fat or thin you are. If the latter, the view.

Comment: Good question. The texts are stored raw.

Comment: Then I would say in the view. In CakePHP I'd probably write a helper to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store them raw, then it belongs to the View.

A View Helper is one choice. Another would be a [custom ob_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) that post-processes the rendered HTML before it is delivered. Since you mentioned, the post might also contain BBCode, you could also consider using a [BBCode parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), which would handle the emoticons as well.

Personally, I think emoticons are so useless, that the server shouldnt be bothered with it. So I'd probably put that responsibility in a JavaScript that will parse and replace on page load. Did a quick Google and think you could use http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-emotify/

Comment: Handling emoticons with JavaScript makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the suggestion and the great answer overall!